Unison - Ignore Path, File, Name
I have unsion installed on two servers, server1.local and server2.local. The config file is stored on server1.local.
I can successfully sync the files between the two servers. However, I have a path called DVR_Aufnahmen containing some files, which I do not like to sync, i.e. I want to ignore this directory. The absolute directory is /mnt/data/Media/DVR_Aufnahmen.
I tried the following configuration. Unfortunately, all directories are synced. I cannot ignore the DVR_Aufnahmen.  Any ideas?
#roots of the synchronization
root = /mnt/data
root = ssh://server2.local//mnt/data

# paths to sync
path = test
path = Media

# paths to ignore
ignore = Name DVR_Aufnahmen
ignore = Name Media/DVR_Aufnahmen

ignore = Path DVR_Aufnahmen
ignore = Path Media/DVR_Aufnahmen
ignore = Path */DVR_Aufnahmen/*
ignore = Path */Media/DVR_Aufnahmen/*

ignore = Path {DVR_Aufnahmen}
ignore = Path {Media/DVR_Aufnahmen}

